# How to stop listview from scrolling to default when re binding the item

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a `ListView` loaded with items.

When I update the model and try to re-bind the `ItemsSource` the `ListView` scrolls to the default position.

I there a way to prevent the `ListView` from scrolling when re-binding the data or scroll to the previous position.

I am using `ObservableCollection` for the list.

Comment: Cant you simply say ``var oldSelectedItem = listView.SelectedItem; listView.ItemsSource = new Stuff(); listView.SelectedItem = oldSelectedItem;`` ?

Comment: This is also will not fix the issue. My List Item size is high i.e each list item will cover entire screen.  **listView.SelectedItem = oldSelectedItem** Will again scroll to top of the oldSelectedItem not the exact position how it was. I have tried this too. But no luck.

Comment: I have made it working by implementing **ViewCell Render** class and **tableview.BeginUpdates, tableView.EndUpdates** methods inside property event changed property of the control.